# read a small file contail a Long number in one goal and get ride of the carriage return \n

Tags: java, io, echo, java-io

I have a small file test.txt contains a Long number inside while another piece of java code to read the Long constantly from the file.

Here is the steps:

Run

```
echo "123" > test.txt
```

then if you go to the test.txt file, vim test.txt -> :set list, you will see the file looks like:

```
123$
```

I have a piece of java code does the following:

```
byte[] testBytes = File.readAllBytes(test.txt);  
String testString = new String(testBytes);  // in debug mode, testString looks like "123\n"
long bytesEverRead = Long.parseLong(testString);  // this line throws exception because parseLong("123\n") won't work
```

As you can see above, "123\n" is being read from the file which cause my parseLong failed. How can I read 123 out from test.txt without having \n with it. What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
String testString = new String(testBytes).trim();
long bytesEverRead = Long.parseLong(testString);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (introduced in Java 5).

There are several examples on the Javadoc page, but in your case it would be as easy as:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
long bytesEverRead = sc.nextLong();
```